# making the modal fill the entire parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a modal fill the parent div, when i gave it position absolute and its parent position relative, it just pushed the other elements , didnt go over them for some reason.
tried setting height to 100% and same for width, the parent is the main tag,

i want the modal to open from the header to the footer, and get a z-index so its the one thats clickable, and the other elements to stay behind it until closed again with display none

how do i make it go over the other elements?

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-light;
}

.upload-modal {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1001;
}

main {
  flex: auto;
  background-color: #f3f0ec;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <section class="user-options">
    <a href="" class="sign-up">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="" class="login">Login</a>
  </section>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
  <p>Create a meme from JPG, GIF or PNG images. Edit your image and make a meme. </p>
</header>
<main>
  <section class="upload">
    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
      <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
      <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    </div>
    <p>Or</p>
  </section>
  <button class="meme-template">
                Select meme template 
            </button>

  <section class="meme-template-modal hide">
    <div class="images-container">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="upload-modal hide">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <h2>Meme editor</h2>
      <section class="user-controls">
        <button> Add Text</button>
        <button> Add Image</button>
        <button class="generate">Generate meme</button>
      </section>
    </div>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you do is add `position: absolute;` to an element, that does not yet affect the position where it will appear. It will simply appear where it would without `position: absolute;` unless you specify where to position it relative to the next positioned ancestor.

To specify that (and also to make it fully stretch), add the positions:

```
.upload-modal {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
}
```